# How to save URI to file

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, hololens

I am trying to stream MRC video from the Hololens to my PC; there is a [repo that does this](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityCompanionKit/blob/master/MixedRemoteViewCompositor/Samples/LowLatencyMRC/UWP/Viewer/Playback.xaml.cs), but plays the URI to a Media Player, and I'm trying to get it saved to a file. How can I do this? I've already tried using  HttpClient, but the app seems to crash when I send a request to the URI. In the link that I attached, there is a StartPlayback() method that sets the source property of the Media Player to the URI, and it seems to work fine. I tried to modify it in the below way:

```
private async void StartPlayback()
    {
        Uri link = new Uri(string.Format("mrvc://{0}:{1}", this.txAddress.Text, this.txPort.Text));
        this.videoPlayer.Source = link;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var response = await client.GetAsync(link))
        {
            // make sure our request was successful
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            // read the filename from the Content-Disposition header
            var filename = response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;

            // read the downloaded file data
            var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

            // Where you want the file to be saved
            var destinationFile = Path.Combine("C:\\Users\\orsteam\\Documents", filename);

            // write the steam content into a file
            using (var fileStream = File.Create(destinationFile))
            {
                stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
        }
        this.bnStart.IsEnabled = false;
        this.bnStop.IsEnabled = true;
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a problem with your code?

Comment: I keep getting a 'Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Net.Http.dll' - even when I comment out the response block it crashes, so it seems that the problem is coming from await client.getAsync(link)

Answer (score 1):

In Unity, you don't have access to HttpClient. You can change to use the [WWW](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) class.
Remember to check the `Internet Client` Capability.

Comment: Sorry, I think that you made it in Unity because you added that tag.